# Proving a set is a vector subspace

Tags: abstract-algebra

In the space $\mathbb{R_3}[x]$ polynomials of degree 3 at most, a set is given:
$$
  V = \{p \in \mathbb{R_3}[x]; p''(1) = p'(1), p(1) = 0 \} 
$$
Prove that $V$ is a vector subspace in $\mathbb{R_3}[x]$

I've tried working on it but i'm really not sure if this is correct:

Let $p, q \in \mathbb{R_3}$

$$(\alpha p + \beta q)(1) = \alpha p(1) + \beta q(1) = 0 + 0 = 0$$

$$\begin{align}(\alpha p'' + \beta q'')(1) & = \alpha p''(1) + \beta q''(1) \\ & = \alpha p'(1) + \beta q'(1) \\ & = (\alpha  p' + \beta q')(1)\end{align}$$

Comment: Hello. Yes, it's correct.

Comment: That's all right, good work. There's just one more thing I would look for in a complete answer to the question - the closure of $V$ under addition and scalar multiplication, in addition to the given properties of the superset $\mathbb R_3,$ account for all of the axioms which $V$ must fulfill as a vector space except for the inclusion of an additive identity. (the zero vector) So essentially to finish you just need to show that $p(x) = 0$ is in $V.$

Comment: @StephenDonovan That's not necessary to show as a vector subspace is defined to be a set of vectors $V$ such that $V$ is closed under sum and under product by scalars. That's what martin259 just did.

Comment: @AnaS.H. Sorry, it somehow totally slipped my mind that the closure under multiplication covers the zero vector because you can just multiply by $0$, my bad. In fairness though your definition of a subspace is slightly incorrect: a subspace is a vector space and therefore must meet all 10 of the vector space axioms, it just happens that if you have the two closures for the subspace then the rest follows by the properties of the parent space.

Comment: You should prove the set is not empty. And your last chain of equalities should at some point note that you get zero...

Answer (score 1):

You should just mention that $0$ which is the zero polynomial lies in $V$ which shows non-emptiness and that $(c\cdot p)$ lies in $U$ for all $p\in U$ and $c\in \Bbb{R}$ .

That is $(c\cdot p)(1)= c\cdot p(1)= 0 $ and $(c\cdot p)''(1) = c\cdot p''(1)=c\cdot p'(1)=(c\cdot p)'(1) $ .

To prove that a non-empty subset $U$ is a subspace of a vector space $V$ over a field $\Bbb{F}$, you need to show that $u_{1}+u_{2}\in U\,,\forall u_{1},u_{2}\in U$ and $c\cdot u\in U\,,\forall u\in U,c\in\Bbb{F} $ (in this case $c\in \Bbb{R}$).